# Iteratively adding variables to an lm() function in R?

Tags: r, tidyverse

Simple question, but I'm finding myself boggled.

I'm looking to make a loop that will continuously add variables to the IV of an lm() function. I would test the results of the LM until a condition is met. I'm just having trouble finding a way to dynamically adding variables to the IV part of the regression, one at a time.

The 1st iteration would look like:

```
lm(Y ~ X, data = data)
```

The second iteration like:

```
lm(Y ~ X + X2, data = data)
```

The third iteration like:

```
lm(Y ~ X + X2 + X3, data = data)
```

And so on...

If any of you could point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it very much.

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to find the best subset of variables for the LM there are packages just for that. Check out examples here https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/2897_9220b21cfc0c43a396ff9abf122bb351.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative way is to use `Y ~ .` as the formula and provide the subset of data as required. Here, `.` means "all columns not otherwise in the formula" (see `?formula`). Using `mtcars` as an example:

```
Y <- 'mpg'
Xs <- names(mtcars)[-1]

fits <- lapply(seq_along(Xs), function(x){
    lm(paste(Y, '~ .'), data = mtcars[, c(Y, Xs[1:x])])
})
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `reformulate` to create the formula after passing the independent variables as a `list`

```
out <- lapply(list("X", c("X", "X2"), c("X", "X2", "X3")), 
      function(x) lm(reformulate(x, response = "Y"), data = data))
```

Or make it automated

```
Xs <- setdiff(names(data), "Y")
ind <- sequence(seq_along(Xs))
lapply(split(Xs[ind], cumsum(ind == 1)), function(x) 
          lm(reformulate(x, response = "Y"), data = data))
```